# android studio and creating a main menu screen

Tags: javascript, android, xml, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio and I am confused on where to start. Where should I put the code for the main menu screen?

How do I create a main menu screen like this layout:

[image]

I looked on https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#xml and could not find the layout similar to this layout. Has anyone tried to create this layout before? If so, can you please show me how to create it in javascript or xml? Please and thank you.

Comment: create the menu in the menu folder and then use it in anywhere

Comment: and moreover for your Main Menu Layout as shown in the image you can use buttons to achieve the same thing